# wpf combobox padding

Tags: wpf, combobox

This is a simple question

How do you remove the space between the content of a combobox and the border of it. E.g. If the selection of a combobox is "Selection 1" then the "S" is drawn at the very top left of the ComboBox control with no whitespace spacing between it and top left portion of the control.

I did this

```
<ComboBox Padding="0"/>
```

Even this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
  </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The specified ComboBox above is within a ListView GridViewColumn. Maybe that's messing with something.

This doesn't remove the padding. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least, not with the default template. You'd have to write your own. The default template includes this:

```
<DockPanel Margin="2">
    <TextBox .../>
</DockPanel>
```

That'll be a hard-coded margin. About the best you could do with the default template is use a negative padding to offset the hard-coded margin:

```
<ComboBox Padding="-2">
    <ComboBoxItem >Selected</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Expression Blend this is trivial:

1. Right-click the ComboBox and select `Edit Control Parts (Template)` - `Edit A Copy`.
2. Remove the `Margin="2"` from the beginning of the template.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did nothing for me. I had to override the ContentPresenter Margin value in the template like this:

```
                            <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            ...
                            Margin="0"
                            .../>
```

This is the full Style if you want to test it yourself.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton
                            Name="ToggleButton"
                            ClickMode="Press"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsHitTestVisible="false"
                            Padding="0">
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Border
                                        x:Name="Border"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Popup
                            Name="Popup"
                            AllowsTransparency="True"
                            Focusable="False"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid
                                Name="DropDown"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    BorderBrush="#888888"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#888888"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```